# Check for consecutive days in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have this code to check for consecutive dates in PHP:

```
$dates = "2017-02-26, 2017-02-27, 2017-03-01";
$dates = explode(',', $dates);

$conseq = array(); 
$ii = 0;
$max = count($dates);

for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
    $conseq[$ii][] = date('Y-m-d',$dates[$i]);

    if($i + 1 < $max) {
        $dif = $dates[$i + 1] - $dates[$i];
        if($dif >= 90000) {
            $ii++;
        }   
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```

The problem is this code do not make the work at 100%.

It should make one array with the consecutive days and another one for each separate days like  this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 2017-02-26
    [1] => 2017-02-27
)
Array (
    [0] => 2017-03-01
)
```

Anyone to help me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below answer

```
<?php
$dates = "2017-02-26, 2017-02-27, 2017-03-01";
$dates = explode(',', $dates);

$conseq = array(); 
$ii = 0;
$max = count($dates);

for($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
    $conseq[$ii][] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates[$i]));

    if($i + 1 < $max) {
        $dif = strtotime($dates[$i + 1]) - strtotime($dates[$i]);
        if($dif >= 90000) {
            $ii++;
        }   
    }
}

print_r($conseq);
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in foreach loop something like this and then filter the array values by month.

```
$dates = "2017-02-26, 2017-02-27, 2017-03-01";
$date_arr = explode(',', $dates);
$filter = array();
foreach( $date_arr as $date ){
   $filter[date('m', strtotime($date))][] = $date; 
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($filter);
```

Comment: And what about the consecutive dates on more than one month ?